# Can I set the same header for a group rather then setting an environmental variable for each individual request within a group

Tags: paw-app

I am using the same **Authorization Header** for all of my API requests. Instead of having to set an Environment Variable and individually adding it to each Request, I'd like to set it at the group level so it applies to all Requests within the group.

Does Paw currently offer this and if not, can we have this added to it's toolbox? [Postman currently does](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#inheriting-auth) this and it would be nice to have in Paw.